# Gradle applicationId with flavors for Android

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-productflavors

I want to upload my application in the Google Play store but before it goes live i want to test it. There is a testing mode in the app and i want the production applicationId to be like

```
com.company.product
```

but i want also to have 2 flavours for testing like

```
com.company.product.alpha
&&
com.company.product.beta
```

How should my app build.gradle be like?

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  
        ....

flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        product {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".product"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }

        alpha {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".product.alpha"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
     
        beta {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".product.beta"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
    }
```

.....Or i suppose to have it like??

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.product"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  
        ....

flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {

        alpha {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".alpha"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
     
        beta {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.company.product"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 30
    flavorDimensions "application"
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

productFlavors {
    alpha {
        dimension "application"
        applicationIdSuffix ".alpha"
        versionNameSuffix "-alpha"
        buildConfigField "String", "FLAVOR_TYPE", '"alpha"'
    }
    beta {
        dimension "application"
        applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
        versionNameSuffix "-beta"
        buildConfigField "String", "FLAVOR_TYPE", '"beta"'
    }
    production {
        dimension "application"
        applicationIdSuffix ""
        versionNameSuffix ""
        buildConfigField "String", "FLAVOR_TYPE", '"production"'
    }
}
```

Set `applicationIdSuffix` and `versionNameSuffix` for each flavour and keep empty for production one. In that way you can distribute `com.company.product.alpha` and `com.company.product.beta` for alpha and beta flavours.